# Adding zeros after the decimal point

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting

I have a certain dictionary key and its values that I wish to print out in a string in a certain fashion. The key and its values is:

```
 'HUF': (315.89, 307.09)
```

and the desired output is:

```
HUF....315.8900....307.0900
```

So far, I have used the following code:

```
'{i:.<8}{e[0]:.<3f}{e[1]:.>12}'.format(i=i, e=e)
```

in which "i" represents the key and "e[0]" and "e[1]" represent the values. But when I run this code the output is:

```
HUF.....315.890000......307.09
```

Is there any way to to print the first number without the two added zeros?

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> i='HUF'
>>> e=(315.89, 307.09)
```

Try:

```
>>> '{i:.<8}{e[0]:.<.04f}{e[1]:.>12.04f}'.format(i=i, e=e)
'HUF.....315.8900....307.0900'
```

You can also separate the field width formatting from the float formatting like so:

```
>>> '{:.<8}{:.<s}{:.>12}'.format(i, *[format(x, '.04f') for x in e])
'HUF.....315.8900....307.0900'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But your code also appends two zeroes to the second number.

Comment: You posted `HUF....315.8900....307.0900` as desired output. What is the desired output?

Comment: A little improvement to the @dawg's answer:
`'{:.<8}{:.<s}{:.>12}'.format(i, *[str(float(format(x, '.04f').strip('0'))) for x in e])`
This removes the trailing zeros and properly handles formating if the number is actually integer (in this case it prints for example 5.0).

Comment: @AndrejDebenjak: Thanks for the comment. However, 1) `format(5, '.04f')` already converts an int to a float representation and 2) I believe the intent of the OP was to get a fixed number of decimals -- `format(9.99999999999, '.04f')` rounds the representation to `'10.0000'`. Why strip trailing zeros, represent that with 4 decimals, then convert to a float?

Comment: My answer refers to the last line of the original question: "Is there any way to to print the first number without the two added zeros?" For this, my answer should do the work. Otherwise, I agree with your comment @dawg.